# Activate [Required] on specific submit buttons ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, controller

**MODEL**

```
namespace Maintenance_.Models
{
    public class IndexModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]
        public string ID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "*")]        
        public string firstName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

In my View I have three Submit type button (Search, Save, and Update), My problem is that when I click the Search button the *[Required(ErrorMessage = "Needed Info")]* will be active. Is there a code the can make my **required** active only when *Save* and *Update* button is click?

**EDIT**

**View**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    //Some codes...

    <button type="submit" id="search" name="SubmitButton" value="search" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button> 

    //Some codes

    <button name="SubmitButton" value="update" id="update" type="submit" style = "float:right;margin-right:10px; border-radius:5px;" class="btn btn-default" @ViewBag.disableUpdate><i class='fa fa-edit fa-fw'></i>Update</button>
    <button name="SubmitButton" value="save" id="save" type="submit" style = "float:right;margin-right:10px; border-radius:5px;" class="btn btn-default" disabled><i class='fa fa-save fa-fw'></i>Save</button>
}
```

Comment: If your validated fields are on different form than the search button this should not be happening.

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your HTML. Mainly the forms.

Comment: I have add my View in my EDIT

Comment: Would it be possible to move the search to a different form? If you want to post different fields through search and save/update it would make sense. Also it would make this validation problem non existant.

Comment: That was my first plan, But in my controller **public actionresult Index(string SubmitButton)** I have this. that's why I can't transfer it to a different form.

Comment: Why would this prevent you from making 2 forms? Also from this one line, I suspect your controller logic is pretty messed up. Look at this [excellent post about bindings](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2009/04/27/6-tips-for-asp-net-mvc-model-binding.aspx). Will help you sanitize your code.

Answer (score 1):

I think for search operation **you do not need any submit button**, rather a **normal button** will be good enough.

*Use button and apply `button click` event to perform search operation*.

**This would ensure your validator to work only when update and save buttons are clicked**

Comment: I beg to differ. Using submit for submit is not bad practice.

Comment: I didnt meant to say its a bad practice. You can also do it with out submit

Answer (score 0):

Basically, this can be by JQuery :
Example:

```
$("document").ready(function () {
    $("#MyForm").valid({
         ...do Something
    });
});
```

or `$.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#MyForm");`

or Action part

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ID,Title,ReleaseDate,Genre,Price,Rating")] MyModel obj)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.MyModel.Add(obj);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there are DataAttributes that make unobtrusive validation behave this way, but you can manually disable validation with javascript on submit, like this for example:

```
$("#search").click(function (e) {
    var $this = $(this),
        $form = $this.closest('form');

    e.preventDefault();

    // "hack" to disable validation on submit
    $form.validate().cancelSubmit = true;
    $form.submit();
})
```

[Source](http://daniellang.net/jquery-validation-disable-on-form-submit/)

EDIT:

Spliting the form into 2 different ones might be better:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    //Fields you want to post in for search

    <button type="submit" id="search" name="SubmitButton" value="search" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button> 
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{    
    //Fields you want to post in for insert/update

    <button name="SubmitButton" value="update" id="update" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" @ViewBag.disableUpdate><i class='fa fa-edit fa-fw'></i>Update</button>
    <button name="SubmitButton" value="save" id="save" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" disabled><i class='fa fa-save fa-fw'></i>Save</button>
}
```

Also since searching and inserting/updating is fundamentally different operations, it would make sense to create different controller actions for this 2 operations.

Comment: I have add my *View* in my question @SoonDead

Comment: I copied your code and paste it in my *SCRIPT* file, I work okay but it can't retrieve my data in my database

Comment: That is an entirely different problem. Actually we have no idea what happens on your server side. You can make a separate question for that providing enough information.